# Is there a difference between these two interface?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
            Task<List<T>> GetAll();
            Task<T> Get(int id);
            Task<T> Add(T entity);
            Task<T> Update(T entity);
            Task<T> Delete(int id);
}
```

AND

```
 public interface IRepository
    {
        Task<List<IEntity>> GetAll();
        Task<IEntity> Get(int id);
        Task<IEntity> Add(IEntity entity);
        Task<IEntity> Update(IEntity entity);
        Task<IEntity> Delete(int id);

    }
```

Or are they the same thing?  Is there any advantage with one or the other?

Comment: Well one is generic while the other isn't, so no, they aren't the same thing.  Whether one has advantages over the other depends entirely on the specific circumstances in which they would be used.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski `IRepository<T>` cannot be covariant in `T`, because both `List<T>` and `Task<T>` are invariant in `T`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I figured it out.